# How to return value in object.entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

As following function I need to iterate a object and return a value that calculated in the loop. But it is not return the calculated value and just return 0.

```
sortWeight: (str, combinations) => {
    Object.keys(combinations).forEach(level => {
        let parts = combinations[level];

        parts.forEach((part, index) => {
            if (str.includes(part)) {
                return (level * 10) + index;
            }
        });
    });

    return 0;
}
```

How i return calculated value if it has that.

Comment: `Object.keys(combinations).forEach` doesn't return anything.  So internal `return` doesn't actually return anything to the outer `function`.

Comment: Try using the `reduce` function to iterate over and return.

Comment: Can you include some example parameters so we can better understand what data you're manipulating?